# Is it possible to split C# Windows Forms Events into their own files?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-forms-designer

I'm developing a **Windows Form** using *.NET 4.7.2*. The issue for me is that I have quite a lot of form elements (buttons, check boxes, etc), they all have several events and my **Form1.cs** file gets filled with events/functions. Is there a way I can make it so instead of having the following within Form1.cs:

```
private void openButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

I'm able to have it within its own file called `openButton_Click.cs`.

Comment: I guess you could create a partial class for every event handler, or you could register a handler from another class with the event. You could even use a library like MediatR to handle all of the events, and hook up some kind of generic handler to all events to dispatch them as MediatR messages. What's your actual goal here?

Comment: @Llama , I am attempting to de-clutter the Form1.cs file so each event has it's own file dedicated to what that event does.

Comment: I would suggest looking at using partial classes then (Form1.Designer.cs and Form1.cs as you get in a new project are already an example of this). It will give you the benefit of having access to all your controls and variables while keeping the code itself separated.

Comment: You can possibly move some "process" code to one or more separate "service" classes. This will also de-clutter your form code.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can, in C# you can create partial classes. Those partial classes consist of more files, that can all be combined into one class. making this totally doable:

file_one.cs:

```
public partial class MyClass {
    public void X(){
    }
}
```

file_two.cs:

```
public partial class MyClass {
    public void Y(){
        X();
    }
}
```

So in your example, you could easily create separate files and organize your code in a way that suits your system best.

But...
In a way, your solution smells a bit weird. It looks to me like you have a lot of lines of code to organize. Using C# there are better ways of doing so instead of partial classes which are (in this case) just a bandage on the wounds. It may be a good idea to re-investigate the code and see if you can extract business logic from the UI and bring that to a separate library naturally organizing your code in a clean and maintainable way.

Comment: A better naming might be "MyClass.X.cs" (or just "MyClass.cs") and "MyClass.Y.cs". That way you keep the files together instead of mixing them with the partials of MyOtherClass. The IDE may even group them that way.